# Implementing relationship in models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models: **Dish** and **DishCategory**. I decided to implement a **"One to many"** relationship.
Here's a migration for **Dish** model:

```
Schema::create('dishes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('dish', 50);
    $table->string('photo');
    $table->double('price', 8, 2);
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->integer('type_id'); /* 1 - menu for delivery; 0 - general menu */
});
```

And a migration for **DishCategory** model:

```
Schema::create('dish_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('category');
});
```

I've created a method called `dish()` in **DishCategory** model:

```
public function dish()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Dish');
}
```

And `dish_category()` in **Dish** model:3

```
public function dish_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DishCategory', 'category_id');
}
```

I'm trying to set up a foreign key in my relationship, so it's been set up in `dish_category()` method as a second parameter of `belongsTo()`. But it doesn't work. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `dish()` relationship definition to:

```
public function dish()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Dish', 'category_id');
}
```

And `dish_category()` is defined correctly.

If you also want to add a [constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), add this to the `dishes` table migration:

```
Schema::table('dishes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('dish_categories');
});
```

Comment: Now, I changed it. Nothing really happened. How can I check if it works or not?

Comment: @КамиловТимур I assume you already have data in DB. For example, you could get and display category of `Dish` with `dd(Dish::find('1')->dish_category);` to check if the relationship works. To check another relationship, you could get and display all `Dish` objects in one category `dd(DishCategory::find(1)->dish);`

Comment: No, I don't have any data in my db. After implementing the relationship I started a migration.

Comment: @КамиловТимур well, add some data if you want to test it.

Comment: I'm testing it with a SQL command "SHOW CREATE TABLE dishes". So, there is no any implementations for foreign key.

Comment: @КамиловТимур you've asked about defining relationships and foreign key. I've shown you how to add a foreign key to it. With the SQL command, you're trying to see the FK constraint and not FK.

Comment: @КамиловТимур I've added a solution for adding constraint too.

Comment: Ooooh now I totally understand the feature. Thank you so much)